# Basic and Simple Explanation of This Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, arrays

I am new to web development and I am currently tackling Javascript.

Can someone please explain to me in simple, plain English, what this code means from start to end.

```js
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];

function countVowels(sentence) {
  let counts = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if(vowels.includes(sentence[i])) {
      counts++;
    }
  }
  return console.log(counts);
}

countVowels('Hello World');
countVowels('AaEeIiOoUu');
countVowels('aaaaa');
```

I am trying to make code that will print out the vowels in a sentence, not count them.

Help please!

Comment: So its bad for starters.. Its itterating over the vowels (wrong because its up to the number of array items) And then counting how many of those are in the sentence (but the sentance can be longer than the array count so the numbers wont make much sense.)

Comment: Use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make code that will print out the vowels in a sentence, not count them.

For this you should iterate over the characters in the sentence itself and then see if that character are in the array of vowels.

```
function countVowels(sentence) {
  let vowelsInSentence = [];
  let counts = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if(vowels.includes(sentence[i]) && !vowelsInSentence.includes(sentence[i])) {
      vowelsInSentence.push(sentence[i]);
    }
  }
  return console.log(vowelsInSentence);
}
```

You can drop half the array too by just forcing all chars `toLowerCase`.

Note : I haven't tested this but it should add all the unique vowels found, add them to the list, and then print them out after.

*Note Note: There are more efficient ways of doing this, but some reading up and playing around will be better to learn.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in printing all vowels in passed sentence, just change your countVowel function is

```
function printVowels(sentence) {
  for(let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if(vowels.includes(sentence[i])) {
      console.log(sentence[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This code will print all vowels present in sentence passed to printVowel function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

1. Creates an array of vowels.
2. You have a function that *counts* the vowels in a sentence that's given as an argument (although you should be looping over the sentence, not the array as the other posters have pointed out).
3. And you're logging the count.

There are other answers here to help correct your code, but here's an alternative.

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the string against vowels using [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). `match` will return an array that you can then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) up into a new string.

```js
function getVowels(sentence) {
  return sentence.match(/[aeiou]/gi).join('');
}

console.log(getVowels('Hello World'));
console.log(getVowels('AaEeIiOoUu'));
console.log(getVowels('aaaaa'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are solving is " how to find all symbols in a string that match a condition (are vowels)"

As @Pogrindis mentioned in their comment, your for loop is incorrect. It iterates over the array of vowels `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']` and checks if symbol in the sentence at position i is a vowel.

Consider this step by step walk through the code:
0. you define array `vowels` 0. a function `countVowels` is defined

1. call `countVowels("Hello World')` step into the function
2. `sentence === 'Hello World'`
3. `for(let i=0; i<vowels.length; i++)` note that vowels is the array defined on top, so the loop will iterate over it. `vowels.length == 10` while `sentence.length === 11` so this loop will never reach the last symbol of `Hello World` ( imagine also if the string is much longer)
4. `if(vowels.includes(sentence[i]))` check if symbol at position `i` ( on first iteration it's 0, so `H`) is in the `vowels` array ( it's not, so `false`)
5. `for` loop continues `i` is then 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9
6. when `i` is 1, 4 and 7 `count` is increased because `vowels.includes(sentence[i])` is true.
7. at last when the for loop is over ( never checked the last letter though) the function returns, but it returns the return value of `console.log` function call - that is `undefined`

To get all the vowels in the sentence you need to make at least two adjustments:

1. iterate over sentence, instead of vowels array so that you always check all the letters in it.
2. instead of counting vowels you need to print them out. I suggest that you actually collect all of them in the array - then it's easy to both count them and print them.

```js
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];

function getVowels(sentence) {
    let vowelsInSentence = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) { // iterate over `sentence`
        if (vowels.includes(sentence[i])) {
            vowelsInSentence.push(sentence[i]);
        }
    }
    return vowelsInSentence; // it is better to return a value, this way code which calls the function can decide what to do with the result
}

console.log(getVowels('Hello World'));
console.log(getVowels('AaEeIiOoUu'));
console.log(getVowels('aaaaa'));
```

and here is a bit more advanced version of the same code:

```js
const vowels = new Set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']); // set is more efficient data structure for lookups

function getVowels(sentence) {
    return sentence
            .split('') // this returns an array of all the letters in a string, i.e. ['H', 'e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']
            .filter(letter => vowels.has(letter)); // this checks every element of an array to match a condition and returns an array of all elements where the check returned `false`
}

console.log(getVowels('Hello World'));
console.log(getVowels('AaEeIiOoUu'));
console.log(getVowels('aaaaa'));
```